# Java - JDBC/Swing - executeUpdate Not Working with BLOB

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, blob

I have encountered a problem, as far as I know this whole code works up until `pst.executeQuery` I just can't see as to why this is the issue. I have an update/insert method and no issues regarding them. I am using a label to display the image, so would it be `photoLabel.setIcon();`or am I just completely off-track. I have one-button for the file chooser which loads the image into the label, the save button (this function) *should* just write to the database in the 12 column/field called Images.

Please Note - The `System.out.Println`for testing purposes, just

```
System.out.println("Working 5");
```

Will not show, hence why I know it's something to do with pst.executeQuery(). I've tried searching the web, used different .execute methods, I've tried to commit the connection and so on. Alas no luck.

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Connection connection = null;

    Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
//  String s = null;
    try {

        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:employeeDatabase.sqlite");
        //connection.setAutoCommit(false);
        System.out.println("Working 1");
         InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File(s));
        System.out.println("Working 2");
         String sql = "insert into employees(Images) values(?)";
         PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            System.out.println("Working 3");
           pst.setBlob(12, is);

            System.out.println("Working 4");


           pst.executeQuery();
           connection.commit();
        System.out.println("Working 5");
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data Inserted");


}
    }

        catch ( Exception e1 ) {


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error");

        }
}});
```

This is the method to select the image via the use of a JFileChooser

```
uploadImage.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                 JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
                 fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
                 FileNameExtensionFilter filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("*.JPG", "jpg","gif","png");      
                 fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
                fileChooser.addChoosableFileFilter(filter);
                 fileChooser.setMultiSelectionEnabled(false);
                 int result = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(null);
                 if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){
                     File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                     String path = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
                     photoLabel.setIcon(ResizeImage(path));
                     s = path;
                      }


                 else if(result == JFileChooser.CANCEL_OPTION){
                     System.out.println("No Data");
                 }
             }
            });
```

Edit -

By not working I mean, I get no errors, program doesn't break. Just the image will not upload to the database and the code `System.out.println("Working 5");` doesn't print to console. So it appears to be stuck/freeze at that point on.

Comment: define *not working*

Comment: @ScaryWombat I get no errors, program doesn't break. Just will not upload the image to database and the code System.out.println("Working 5"); doesn't print to console.

Comment: In you code you have a `try` - are you ignoring the catch?

Comment: @ScaryWombat Yeah, forgot to include the catch exception in my original post. I've added it now. It appears to only get up to `pst.executeQuery` and then got to the `catch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, double check the table structure for table `employees` and column `Images` with correct type

Then, set the correct placeholder for input in the prepared statement, there is only one

```
pst.setBlob(1, ...
```

Then, use this approach instead

```
private byte[] readFile(String file) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = null;
    try {
        File f = new File(file);
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(f);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (int len; (len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1;) {
            bos.write(buffer, 0, len);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        System.err.println(e2.getMessage());
    }
    return bos != null ? bos.toByteArray() : null;
}
```

With

```
pst.setBytes(1, readFile(s));
```

Finally, call

```
pst.executeUpdate();
```

Source: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/jdbc-read-write-blob/

Comment: Ok, you lost me with First, set the correct placeholder for input in the prepared statement, there is only one. But thank you for your reply. :)

Comment: Read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html it depends on the #of ? in the statement.  first one is 1 second is 2 and so on.

Comment: I've added the code but get an error with the private byte[] readFile(Stringfile) = Syntax error on token "readFile", AnnotationName expected

Comment: Dude, it worked!!!! Sorry about me being stupid, it's pretty late. 03:36AM.... Enjoying the Christmas Holidays hahah! Thank you, I've accepted your answer. Seriously dude. Thank you so much! <3

Comment: Glad you have it sorted.  Happy Holidays.

Comment: You too buddy! :)